# Combinations and Permutations question (why certain combinations are not equivalent?)

Tags: permutations, combinations

This is a question from my data management textbook.

8. A project team of 6 students is to be selected
   from a class of 30.

a) How many different teams can be selected?

b) Pierre, Gregory, and Miguel are students
in this class. How many of the teams
would include these 3 students?

c) How many teams would not include
Pierre, Gregory, and Miguel?

The textbook answers are A)593775 b)2925 c)590850

I solved part a) by doing 30C6 which was no problem. I got the desired answer of 593775.

I was able to solve part b) by doing 27C3=2925 to find all teams when Pierre, Gregory and Miguel are part of the team. But I don't understand why I couldn't solve using the indirect method of 30C6-27C6 which equals 297765.

For part C I was able to solve using the indirect method of 30C6-27C3 which equals the given answer of 590850. But why could I not solve this using the indirect method of 27C6, which I believe would be choosing 6 students out of the other 27?

Comment: Your "indirect method" for b) counts the number of ways to choose the team so that **at least one** of our three heroes is on the team.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For part (b), the correct way to think about choosing the team is that Pierre, Gregory, and Miguel automatically occupy three of the positions in the team and then there are 27 people left, of which you must pick 3. Hence the total number of teams is $\binom{27}{3}$. The reason that $\binom{30}{6}-\binom{27}{6}$ doesn't give you the same answer is that $\binom{27}{6}$ is the number of teams that don't include any of Pierre, Gregory, or Miguel (i.e. all three are not part of the team). However, you would also need to subtract off teams that just had Pierre, or just had Gregory, or just had Miguel, or teams that have exactly two of them. This is the due to the [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).

For part (c), I think the confusion is coming from the wording of the question. When they say "how many teams would not include Pierre, Gregory, and Miguel" they mean how many teams would not include all three members (so, for example, you could have a team with just Pierre and Gregory and four other members but not Miguel). By using $\binom{27}{6}$ you are looking at all teams that don't include any of Pierre, Gregory, or Miguel.

Comment: Ok, thank you. This makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

For b), that is ypur indirect method calculates the number of teams which include *none* of Pierre, Gregory and Miguel. It does not take into account the teams  that contain only some of these students.

Similar reason for question c): a team that does not include these three students may include some of them.

Answer (score 0):

> a) How many different teams can be selected?

Select 6 of 30 students. $\rm {^{30}C_{6}}$

> b) Pierre, Gregory, and Miguel are students in this class. How many of the teams would include these 3 students?

Select those 3 students, then select 3 *others* of the remaining 27.  $\rm{^3C_3}\;{^{27}C_3}$

> c) How many teams would not include Pierre, Gregory, and Miguel?

Interpreting as: "not include all of"

Use the Law of Complements: $\rm{^{30}C_6}-{^3C_3}\;{^{27}C_3}$

> not asked) How many teams would not include Pierre, Gregory, *or* Miguel?

Interpret as: "not include any of"

Select 6 students from the 27 who are not those three.  $\rm{^{27}C_6}$